# How to convert from BotFrameworkAdapter to CloudAdapter

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a working set of code:

```
            await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).CreateConversationAsync(
            teamsChannelId,
            serviceUrl,
            credentials,
            conversationParameters,
            (t, ct) =>
            {
                conversationReference = t.Activity.GetConversationReference();
                _BotProfile.QueueCardList.TryAdd(guid.ToString(), t.Activity.Id);
                _BotProfile.RequestList.TryAdd(guid.ToString(), conversationReference);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            cancellationToken);
```

That I'm looking to switch to CloudAdapter.  I've tried:

```
        string audience = "";

        await ((CloudAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).CreateConversationAsync(
            _appId,
            teamsChannelId,
            serviceUrl,
            audience,
            conversationParameters,
            (t, ct) =>
            {
                conversationReference = t.Activity.GetConversationReference();
                _BotProfile.QueueCardList.TryAdd(guid.ToString(), t.Activity.Id);
                _BotProfile.RequestList.TryAdd(guid.ToString(), conversationReference);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            cancellationToken);
```

I've also tried https:\api.botframework.com for the value of audience to no avail.

Comment: Have you compared your implementation with those in the [botframework-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repo? For instance, [02.echo-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs) is a clean, simple example.